# Why does C# round (100-1)/2 to 49 instead of 50?

Tags: c#, integer, int, rounding

According to my calculator: (100-1) / 2 = 49.5

If I have an int like this:

```
int mid = (100 - 1) / 2
```

And printing mid will give me:

```
49
```

Why will C# give me 49 instead of 50? Aren't you supposed to round to the next whole number if it is .5 so that the number would be 50?

Comment: No. Integer division always rounds down.

Comment: Does it round towards 0?

Comment: @EliSadoff - technically it truncates, but the effect is the same

Comment: @ChrisF is right it is technically a truncation.

Comment: The curly brace languages like you trick you into integer division.  It used to be a lot faster.  If you want 49.5 then you have to use floating point division.  One of the two operands must be a *double*, usually done with a (double) cast.  But easy here, divide by 2.0 instead.

Comment: @HansPassant or put a 'd' suffix on one arg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When performing integer division (by which we mean both arguments are integral types) the CLR will *truncate* the result; effectively rounding down for positive results.

If you want "standard" or midpoint rounding, you need to explicitly use [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) and floating point division (at least one argument is `float`, `double` or `decimal`).

Comment: Minor thing: C# doesn't do the truncation, it merely emits a `div` op code, which is handled by the CIL.

Comment: @Rob Ok.... technically C# doesn't do *anything* but emit op codes. I'll fix it though :)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't rounding but integer arithmetic which truncates the floating point number, so

> (100 - 1) / 2 == 99 / 2 = 49.5 which truncates to 49

and

> (100 - 1) / -2 = 99 / -2 = -49.5 which truncates to -49

If you want real rounding then you must make at least one of the variables a floating point value and then call `Math.Round` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, integer division will truncate. This makes sense since `99 % 2 == 1` and you would expect that subtracting the modulus from the original value wouldn't change the division result, i.e. (99/2 == (99-(99%2))/2), so 99/2 = 98/2